# How to make an ArrayAdapter (android studio)

Tags: xml, string, arraylist, android-studio

I want to display 10 elements/strings that I have in my java file, the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String[]>Numbers = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String[] ListOfNumbers  = new String[10];

        ListOfNumbers[0] = "One";
        ListOfNumbers[1] = "Two";
        ListOfNumbers[2] = "Three";
        ListOfNumbers[3] = "Four";
        ListOfNumbers[4] = "Five";
        ListOfNumbers[5] = "Six";
        ListOfNumbers[6] = "Seven";
        ListOfNumbers[7] = "Eight";
        ListOfNumbers[8] = "Nine";
        ListOfNumbers[9] = "Ten";
```

And I would like to display all of those in the layout.

**UPDATE:**
I added, in the java file, this:

```
ListView _list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id._list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1  , ListOfNumbers );

_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And in the xml:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/_list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
```

But now that I run the Emulator, it collapses.

Comment: check this : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP didn't do an even minimal research on the argument.

Comment: I tried that one a while ago, but I don't understand a bit.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListView _list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id._list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1  , ListOfNumbers );

_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: try to run on any device... or post logcat

Comment: I solved the problem already, thanks, Try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603087/make-some-strings-of-a-listview-bold-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603087/make-some-strings-of-a-listview-bold-android-studio for this you have to implement a custom arryadapter

Answer (score 0):

Make an `ArrayAdapter - listAdapter`
Then you can set the adapter to a listView by using `setAdapter`

```
listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Then you can add items to the listadapter by using `listAdapter.add`

You'll see the items in your listview.